# Facebook / Twitter login integration into JASIG CAS

Tags: java, twitter-oauth, cas, facebook-oauth, spring-social

Has anyone had any success integrating the Spring Social framework ( http://www.springsource.org/spring-social ) into the JASIG CAS single sign on solution ( http://www.jasig.org/cas )?

I am trying to implement Facebook / Twitter login and after consideration of various implementation solutions (ie. custom OAuth authentication, Scribe, etc) I have decided to go with Spring Social as CAS already heavily uses the Spring Framework.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  CAS was built for internal appliacations.  CAS works by pointing to a USER datastore such an Active Directory.  In order for CAS to work with Facebook or Twitter, CAS would need to connect to Facebook's user DB - which we know is not possible.

Comment: [https://github.com/leleuj/cas-pac4j-oauth-demo]

Answer (score 1):

The CAS server codebase has just accepted a module that adds support for the OAuth protocol. You should be able to leverage that functionality to be able to authN into relevant services that support OAuth.

See here for more info: https://github.com/Jasig/cas/tree/master/cas-server-support-oauth